# Add Forum programmatically to IBM Connections Community

Tags: api, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am trying to add a forum topic and then forum entry to a community.
Following the IBM API documentation, I am posting the Atom entry to this URL:/communities/service/atom/community/forum/topics?communityUuid=

The Atom entry I use as the following format (the example coming from the API documentation):
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<entry 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
 xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" 
 xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">`
`<category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="forum-topic"/>`
`<title type="text">TEXT OF TOPIC</title>`
`</entry>`

Each time I get a 200 answer.
I tried with the playground, same result.

Do you know if the URL I am using is correct? Do you know if the Atom entry document is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, was able to find the solution with help from @paul.

The URL you need to post the Atom document is: 
/forums/atom/topics?communityUuid=

The Atom document should look like this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">`
`<title type="text">Test</title>`
`<category term="forum-topic" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type">
</category>`
`<content type="text">
test
</content>`
`<snx:communityUuid xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">19aa4e90-9307-46f1-9b69-5a8965e8ed61</snx:communityUuid>`
`</entry>`

Answer (score 0):

so the URL is correct.
The body is most likely not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0">
<title type="text">Test</title>
<category term="forum-topic" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type">
</category>
<content type="html">
&lt;p dir="ltr"&gt;
Test
&lt;/p&gt;
</content>
<snx:communityUuid xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">3a246a15-b4d6-44e1-a01d-1c3d89f1f9a4</snx:communityUuid>
</entry>
```

Notice the additional attribute 
`<snx:communityUuid xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">3a246a15-b4d6-44e1-a01d-1c3d89f1f9a4</snx:communityUuid>`

When you post, you need to reference the community Id.

Comment: Thanks. You have 2 <entry> in the document with the same <category>. Is that normal?

Comment: Thanks. I still get a 200 answer, and no Forum topic created. Is it working for you?